# How Can I get Sed to Split on a Unicode Character on a Mac?

Tags: macos, unicode, sed

I have a log document where the string to split columns on is just the character \x01 (doesn't map to anything real in unicode, so it's safe). When I run the following on the phrase "This is \x01" on a CentOS box, I get:

```
cat ~/temp1 | sed s/\x01/meh/
this is meh
```

On a Mac, I get:

```
cat ~/temp1 | sed s/\x01/meh/
this is
```

Which is identical to trying to cat the original.

Alternatively, running a Perl one liner on this on a Mac as:

```
cat ~/temp1 | perl -e 'while ( my $line = <>) {$line =~ s/\x01/meh/g; print $line;}'
```

gets me:

```
this is meh
```

So, my conclusion thus far is that sed on a Mac hates unicode for some reason. Anyone have any ideas why/ how to fix it?

Comment: When I do `echo "This is \x01"` on my Mac I just get: `This is \x01` instead of `this is`, Am I missing anything?

Comment: Yeah, I mean the unicode character that \x01 references. Just typing \x01 into a text file will just treat each character as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GNU sed from the [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) package [gsed](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=gsed).

**Edit:** Documentation of GNU sed is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html).